At metro station A, would a sign say "To station B" or "For station B"?
I thought only "to station B" is correct, but a sign in my country says the other, so I'm pretty confused now.
Are both of them correct? If so, why is "for" also acceptable?


Where is 'my country'?

Let's see this sign, please.  "For" indicates purpose, and might be used to label what something (eg a train or a passage) is.  To indicates direction.  But in most cases a sign would indicate direction by an arrow, not by a prepostion  as "← Station B"

Oh I just added the picture. It's in Vietnam. How does it matter which country it is in though? Is there a regional difference in the ways signs    say?

I usually use "my country" because I want to receive a broad, general answer that is applicable to a wider range of nations.

If I were in Station A and I saw a sign saying "to Station B", I would expect that Station A and Station B are close together and connected by a tunnel or something like that and the sign was telling me how to walk to Station B.

On a road sign, it is (usually) obvious that a place name is a "distant direction".
At a train station however, there is a need to distinguish the name of the station itself, from platform indicators.
The full grammatical wording I would expect would be something along the lines of: "This platform for trains to London" but any abbreviation of that would be acceptable, and the shortest possible becomes either:  "for London" or "To London"

Yes. Trains for London and trains for Bristol leave from adjacent platforms at Reading.

For is fine used that way. You can interpret For Station B to mean “in order to reach trains headed in the direction of Station B.” This would be appropriate for instance as a sign indicating a passage leading to the platform where such trains stop.
Another possible meaning of For Station B is “if you wish to reach Station B…”

Thank you! Is "For station B" in common use or is it just understandable?

Dr. X, Acting Head of the Faculty of Foreign Languages at University Y, believes that using "for station B" is incorrect both in terms of grammar and pragmatics in English if it is intended for traffic signs.
"For" can be used in other contexts (not for traffic signs), for example: "This train was carrying a cargo of steel for station B" or "This train is for Brighton only."

On the other hand, "to station B" is grammatically correct but is rarely used. In the U.S., some places use "to + destination," but the word "TO" is capitalized and written smaller than the destination name.

Based on personal experience, Dr. X shared that he has encountered many traffic signs that are "incorrect" according to English standards but are still widely used.
"When speaking or writing a complete sentence, we have more space to express the language than on a traffic sign. That’s why some countries, like the UK or the US, often display the name of the destination along with an arrow indicating direction instead of using 'to + destination.' This approach makes it easier for passengers to visualize when traveling by train," Dr. X said.

Above is the translation of an article related to this matter. What do you think?

It's certainly correct that signs don't have to follow the normal rules of grammar. They need to convey the necessary information in as few words as possible. I seldom travel on the London Underground, but I would find nothing odd about a sign saying, for example "Platform 3 for stations A and B".

Also, a sign at a station saying "To [place]" would imply "Walk this way to get to that place", not "Here is where you catch trains to that place".

Let's see a photo of this sign, to see it in context.  Why do the people and places have single letter names.  What are you trying to hide?

Nothing to hide. But each comment has a word limit so at first I tried to shorten it by using X and Y. It was too long anyway, though. I think you all have given really clear, useful answers already.

Most signs don't have prepostions at all.  The sign inside the station just says "Way Out", "Platform 2", or "District Line" perhaps with an arrow.
Adding a preposition is a bit of a fancy flourish.  "To" indicates direction.  "For" indicates purpose.  It is common, for example, to talk about "The train for London" to mean the train you take if you intend to travel to London.
In this particular situation, "For Station B" makes sense.  It is labeling the platform's purpose.  You can read it as "This is the platform for Ben Thanh."  A literal translation, with a verb "It goes to Ben Thanh." would be unidiomatic.
